# how to create an infopath repeating section

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

I would like to know how will i be able to create a infopath form with the ability to have repeating sections and then submit that information into a sharepoint list.

Hep would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this in my InfoPath form to promote a hidden field that aggregates repeating form data to a plain text multiline field in Sharepoint.  It's refered to as "the double eval" trick.

```
eval(eval(user, 'concat(my:name, ",", my:email, ",", my:access, ";")'), "..")
```

Here are a couple good references:
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/7124/30263.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/04/05/569338.aspx

Comment: Thanks i will check it out and make you know of the result.